# Is there any drawback of using separate theme for each activity in an android application

Tags: android, android-theme

It's traditional to use theme for the whole application. Also we can use multiple themes if it's needed.

My question is what is the maximum number of themes allowed to be used in a single android application ?

Is there any performance issue or any known issue that I need to be concerned about if I use large number of themes defined in styles.xml and define for each activities in my android app.

Answer (score 0):

`Theme` is used for `Views`, views are obtained by `Activity`, `Fragment`, `Dialog` etc...

You can use multiple themes for any layout or views according to your requirement, There is no limitation of using themes for any views.

I think there will be not any kind of performance issue by using separate themes for each `Activity`, because there is not mentioned on developer site.